# Combine multiple replacingOccurrences() with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, regex, string, swift5

I have a String, I would like to **add backslash to specific characters**, because I use markdown and I don't wand to add style it's not wanted.

I tried to make a function, and it's working, but it's not efficient I guess:

```
func escapeMarkdownCharacters(){
      let myString = "This is #an exemple #of _my_ * function"
      var modString = myString.replacingOccurrences(of: "#", with: "\\#")
      modString = modString.replacingOccurrences(of: "*", with: "\\*")
      modString = modString.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: "\\_")
      print(modString) // Displayed: This is \#an exemple \#of \_my\_ \* function 
}
```

**I would like to only have one "replacingOccurences" that work for multiple characters**. I think I could do that with regex but I didn't figure out how. If you have an idea, please share it with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
var modString = myString.replacingOccurrences(of: "[#*_]", with: "\\\\$0", options: [.regularExpression])
```

With a raw string literal:

```
var modString = myString.replacingOccurrences(of: "[#*_]", with: #"\\$0"#, options: [.regularExpression])
```

Result: `This is \#an exemple \#of \_my\_ \* function`

The `options: [.regularExpression]` argument enables the regex search mode.

The `[#*_]` pattern matches `#`, `*` or `_` and then each match is replaced with a backslash (`\\\\`) and the match value (`$0`). Note that the backslash must be doubled in the replacement string because a backslash has a special meaning inside a replacement pattern (it may be used to make `$0` a literal string when `$` is preceded with a backslash).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! I tried that but I didn't write 4 backslash, that's why it was not working