How to replace character with regex and leave the symbol?
I need to add backslash (escape) all special symbols, like (,),+,[,]
Example:
extension String {
    var escaping: String {
        return self.replacing(/[()+]/, with: "\\($0)")
    }
}

let text = "Hello everyone!)) + another one day"
print(text.escaping)

So I need to have in result:
"Hello everyone!\)\) \+ another one day"
Is there any way to do this with regex in swift? Without using replacingOccurrences(of.
var escaping: String {
        return self.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "\\.")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "\\-")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: "\\_")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: ")", with: "\\)")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "\\(")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "\\(")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "\\+")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "!", with: "\\!")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "[", with: "\\[")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: "\\]")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "=", with: "\\=")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "|", with: "\\|")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "{", with: "\\{")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "}", with: "\\}")
    }

Related: Telegram does not escape some markdown characters

You want to use the "new" Regex(Component) and don't want to use replacingOccurrences(of:with:options:), since you can use regular expression with that method, right?

@Larme I want to use regex, to use symbol groups: []. Because if I use replacingOccurrences, there are 14 lines of code.

With replacingOccurrences, you can use regular expression too. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61060905/combine-multiple-replacingoccurrences-with-swift replacingOccurrences(of: "[()+]", with: #"\\$0"#, options: .regularExpression)

You can use the replacing overload that takes a closure (Regex<Output>.Match) -> Replacement, to access the match result, so you can use the match result as part of the replacement.
extension String {
    var escaping: String {
        self.replacing(/[()+.\-_!\[\]=|{}]/) { match in "\\" + match.output }
    }
}

Note that you should escape -, [, and ] in the character class.
Also consider putting \ in the character class. Surely you want to escape that as well (?)

There's a version of replacing(_:subrange:maxReplacements:with:) which takes a closure so you can construct a replacement string from the match. This is its signature
func replacing<Output, Replacement>(
    _ regex: some RegexComponent,
    subrange: Range<Self.Index>,
    maxReplacements: Int = .max,
    with replacement: (Regex<Output>.Match) throws -> Replacement
) rethrows -> Self where Replacement : Collection, Replacement.Element == Character

Here's an example of how to use it
let text = "Hello everyone!))( + another one day"
let replacement = text.replacing(/([()+])/, subrange: text.startIndex ..< text.endIndex) { 
    match in
    "\\" + match.1 
}
print(replacement)


Prints
Hello everyone!\)\)\( \+ another one day

